# Add a custom border to certain cells in a matplotlib / seaborn plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Is it possible to change the heatmap cell color by accessing it via its labels (row and column name). I can add patch to the cell via row and column number but I need to access the cell by its row and column name

Tried to add patches but it does not accept the labels (row and column name),it works if I add the patches via the row and column number but I want to access it via label name

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,5), index=['A','B','C','D','E'], columns=['F','G','H','I','J'])

g = sns.clustermap(df)
ax = g.ax_heatmap

#heatmap cells accessed using their cell location (2,3) to change the cell color or add the border
ax.add_patch(Rectangle((2, 3), 1, 1, edgecolor='blue', lw=-1))
plt.show()

ax = g.ax_heatmap

#I would like to be able to access the cells using the actual labels like ('A','I') to change the cell color, I have been searching but so far I did not find any documentation for this
```

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: @Joe, I have updated the post with the example, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `add_patch` is correct, but you need to give the `fill=False` argument. Otherwise, the whole cell would be painted blue. And then, you can adjust the thickness of the border with the `lw` argument.

```
ax.add_patch(Rectangle((2, 3), 1, 1, edgecolor='blue', fill=False, lw=3))
```

[image]

If you really want to access the row and column by name, you will need to do some gymnastics. Since you're using `clustermap`, it rearranges the row names and column names when displaying the heatmap to optimize for showing the hierarchical linkages. However, if you really need to be able to access the row and column by name, you will have to use the `row_cluster=False` and `col_cluster=False` arguments. By doing this, you'll lose the linkages, but the order of the row and column names in the heatmap will now be the same as in the original dataframe. This allows us to be able to use the row and column name to infer the cell's position in the heatmap, which we can then pass as parameters to `Rectangle`.

```
g = sns.clustermap(df, row_cluster=False, col_cluster=False)
ax = g.ax_heatmap

row = [i for i, x in enumerate(df.index=='A') if x][0]
col = [i for i, x in enumerate(df.columns=='I') if x][0]

ax.add_patch(Rectangle((col, row), 1, 1, edgecolor='blue', fill=False, lw=3))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that `sns.clustermap(df, row_cluster=False, col_cluster=False)` is equivalent to using `sns.heatmap(df)`, except the legend is now present on the right and the row names appear on the left, which I personally feel is a cleaner look if you don't need the hierarchical linkages displayed.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = sns.heatmap(df)

row = [i for i, x in enumerate(df.index=='A') if x][0]
col = [i for i, x in enumerate(df.columns=='I') if x][0]

ax.add_patch(Rectangle((col, row), 1, 1, edgecolor='blue', fill=False, lw=3))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @Haqqani Happy to help. You can upvote and mark this as the answer.